# How to remove gum from hair?

Tags: personal-care, hair, adhesive

Once my little brother fell asleep with gum in his mouth. The gum got stuck to his hair so that we had to cut some of his hair to remove it.

Do you know an alternative way to remove it safely?

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. This appears to be a duplicate of [How do I remove gum from my beard?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-do-i-remove-gum-from-my-beard). If you think that there is any difference, please edit, but for now, I am closing this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best solution would be to rub oil(generally sunflower) in the hair where the chewing gum is.

Comment: Do you know why or how this works? Could you extend the answer a little bit, although is does convey the method clearly.